# TCP server with state information using network library

Tags: c++, poco, boost-asio, ace

I'm writing a tcp server for an online turn-based game. I've already written a prototype using php sockets, but would like to move to C++. I've been looking at the popular network libraries (ASIO, ACE, POCO, LibEvent), but currently unclear which one would best suit my needs:

1) Connections are persistent (on the order of minutes), and the server must be able to handle 100+ simultaneous connections.

2) Connections must be able to maintain state information (user login info). [my php prototype currently requires each client request to contain the login info]

3) Optionally and preferably multi-threaded, but a single process. Prefer not to have 1 thread per connection, but a fixed number of threads working on all open connections.

---

I'm leaning towards POCO's TCPServer or Reactor frameworks, but not exactly sure if they meet my requirements. I think the Reactor is single threaded, and the TCPServer enforces 1:1 threading/connection. Am I correct?

---

In either case case, I'm not exactly sure how to do the most important task of associating login info to a specific connection with connections coming and going at random.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boost.Asio should meet your requirements. The reactor queue can be serviced by [multiple threads](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/threads.html). Using asynchronous methods will enable your design of a [fixed number](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/async.html) of threads servicing all connections.

The [tutorials](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial.html) and [examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html) are probably the best place to start if you are unfamiliar with the library.

Answer (score 0):

You might also take a look at [MUSCLE](https://public.msli.com/lcs/muscle/), a multi-user networking library and server I wrote with this sort of application in mind.  It's BSD-licensed, handles hundreds of users, and includes a server-side database mechanism for storing and sharing any information you want the clients to know about each other.  The server is single-threaded by default, but I haven't found that to be a problem in practice (and it's possible to extend the server to be multithreaded if that turns out to be necessary).